# Adding two numbers together using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I'm trying to understand how to tie code and webpages together and stuff, so I mocked up this basic HTML page to add two numbers together using Javascript.

```js
const first_n = document.getElementById("fnumber")
const second_n = document.getElementById("snumber")

window.onload = function solve(first_n, second_n) {
   var solved = first_n + second_n;

    document.getElementById("solution").innerHTML = solved
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form action="javascript:solve()">
        <label for="fnumber">First n:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="fnumber"><br>
        <label for="snumber">Last n:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="snumber">
        <input type="submit" value="Solve">
    </form>
        <p id="solution"></p>
</body>
```

I know my nomenclature is a mess, don't judge. I just wanna see what I can get to work.

Thoughts on why this isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you! For both the welcome and for the edits @sudo_kaizen. Sorry for the explicit language :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `solve` function on click of the `submit` button. Secondly get the value of the input element inside the function

```js
function solve(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const first_n = document.getElementById("fnumber").value
  const second_n = document.getElementById("snumber").value
  var solved = Number(first_n) + Number(second_n);
  document.getElementById("solution").innerHTML = solved
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fnumber">First n:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="fnumber"><br>
  <label for="snumber">Last n:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="snumber">
  <input type="submit" value="Solve" onclick='solve(event)'>
</form>
<p id="solution"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The window.onload event runs only once and that is when the page loads. At this time, the user has probably not entered any data, hence your fnumber and snumber will not contain any user entered values.

It would be better to trigger your solve function differently, for example associated with a button click via event listener or html on<> attributes

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code, please find the below fix.

```
const first_n = document.getElementById('fnumber');
const second_n = document.getElementById('snumber');

function solve() {
   var solved = parseFloat(first_n.value) + parseFloat(second_n.value);
   document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML = solved;
}
```

1. In your code you are not getting the input Values.
2. You will call the solve function when you click on the submit button and not on page load.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

---

You need to convert the input values from a string to a number. by default the input values are stings.

```js
const solve = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const firstNumber = Number(document.querySelector('#fnumber').value)
  const secondNumber = Number(document.querySelector('#snumber').value)
  
  document.querySelector('#solution').innerText = firstNumber + secondNumber
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fnumber">First n:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="fnumber"><br>
  <label for="snumber">Last n:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="snumber">
  <input type="submit" value="Solve" onclick='solve(event)'>
</form>
<p id="solution"></p>
```

### Example of input default data type (default is string)

---

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#data").value, typeof(document.querySelector("#data").value))
```

```html
<input type="number" id="data" value="3">
```

Even when the input type is `type="number"` the datatype will be a string.

### Bonus

---

You can declare the `solve()` function on `window.onload` if you use an arrow function (`=>`) to declare it, it will not work if you declare the function using a normal `function` declare (`function solve() { ... }`).

```js
window.onload = solve = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const firstNumber = Number(document.querySelector('#fnumber').value)
  const secondNumber = Number(document.querySelector('#snumber').value)
  
  document.querySelector('#solution').innerText = firstNumber + secondNumber
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fnumber">First n:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="fnumber" value="3"><br>
  <label for="snumber">Last n:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="snumber" value="5">
  <input type="submit" value="Solve" onclick='solve(event)'>
</form>
<p id="solution"></p>
```

This has the benefit of running once the window is loaded so as you can see we have set the values of the inputs by default to be `3` and `5` once the example loads it will calculate them without clicking the solve button.